# How to render Flask-Security forgot password form?

Tags: flask, flask-security

I have application with ready UI and I want to add login/logout/register/restore features with `Flask-Security`. Before I worked with that default behavior - when user clicked "forgot password" he was redirected to specific endpoint.

Now I want to have forgot password form on the same page (just in different panel which show when user clicks corresponding link).

I faced an issue that I cannot just add the same form with same endpoint because `Flask-Security` wants CSRF token. I think that I can somehow render its form on page and adjust styles. But I do not know how.

I do not want to turn off `csrf` check unless I definitely know that there is not other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are generating the form dynamically I will assume that you are using AJAX, the [documentation](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html#ajax) speaks about it.

You have to enable the CSRF module with

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect

CsrfProtect(app)
```

you will have access to `csrf_token()` on every page, and you can get it with:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

var csrftoken = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
        }
    }
})
```